# Issue in understanding the logic behind `scrollPlayerIntoView` function

Tags: javascript

actually i am learning the building a platform game and i don't understand the logic behind this code. explain me the logic in the `scrollPlayerIntoView` method used here for player scroll in the game.

i have debug it by using chrome debugger and whenever a negative value given to  `this.dom.scrollLeft` then a zero value is assigned to it automatically. but still i can't understand the logic behind this code.

here is the full [code](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/chapter/16_game.js)
and the function where i stuck is:

```
   DOMDisplay.prototype.scrollPlayerIntoView = function(state) {
   let width = this.dom.clientWidth;
   let height = this.dom.clientHeight;
   let margin = width / 3;

    // The viewport
   let left = this.dom.scrollLeft, right = left + width;
   let top = this.dom.scrollTop, bottom = top + height;

   let player = state.player;
   let center = player.pos.plus(player.size.times(0.5))
                     .times(scale);

    if (center.x < left + margin) {  //   <---i stuck from here cant understand the logic
    this.dom.scrollLeft = center.x - margin;
    } else if (center.x > right - margin) {
    this.dom.scrollLeft = center.x + margin - width;
     }
    if (center.y < top + margin) {
    this.dom.scrollTop = center.y - margin;
     } else if (center.y > bottom - margin) {
     this.dom.scrollTop = center.y + margin - height;
     } 
    };
```

help me to understand the logic or suggest me any way for trying. i have spend so much time in that but cant get to the point what the code is teaching me.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) : "If set to a value less than 0 (greater than 0 for right-to-left elements), scrollLeft is set to 0."

Comment: ok i learned that can you please help me the logic of that function still i am not understand the logic @TimothyLee